# Replacing the content of a file from filename

Tags: text-processing

I want to prepare a script in which content of file is change with its filename.

Suppose I have a FileName `ABC_20161027220153.txt` and content of file is like

```
2000|2000_ABC|04|||0000000000||
```

I want to make a script in which file content are change like below

```
2000|2000_ABC|04|20161027|27.10.2016 22.01.53|0000000000||
```

How can I do this?

Comment: so, how does the decoding work? `20161027` seems like 8 digits after `_` in filename... `27.10.2016` seems like `20161027` rearranged.. okay.. but you lost me at `22.01.53` where did that pop from? perhaps it should be `22.00.00` or your filename should be `ABC_20161027220153.txt` ... imo, awk would be a good tool for this.. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/awk/topics) for some examples and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/ for a free book

Comment: Thanks for your reply... yes file name should be like ABC_20161027220153.txt.. you got my requirement correctly.. i would refer to this book but in the meanwhile can you help me to get some idea and content that how this could be prepare..

Answer (score 1):

There were a few steps to this:

1. awk knows the current filename in the variable `FILENAME`
2. if we haven't split the filename into the decoded elements (hard-coded here to be done on the first line of each new input file), then we use the `substr` function to help us.
3. for each input line, previously split on `|` symbols for us by the `BEGIN` statement, replace fields 4 and 5 with their new values
4. print the reconstructed line

Putting it all together (I named it 'abc.awk'):

```
BEGIN { OFS=FS="|" }

{
  if (FNR == 1) {
    f4=substr(FILENAME, index(FILENAME, "_") + 1, 8);
    f5a=substr(FILENAME, index(FILENAME, "_") + 9, 6);
    f5=substr(f4, 7, 2) "." substr(f4, 5, 2) "." substr(f4, 1, 4) " " \
        substr(f5a, 1, 2) "." substr(f5a, 3, 2) "." substr(f5a, 5, 2);
  }

  $4=f4
  $5=f5
  print $0
}

$ awk -f abc.awk ABC_20161027220153.txt
2000|2000_ABC|04|20161027|27.10.2016 22.01.53|0000000000||
```